# Eclipse to Android show app icons for each class when deployed

Tags: android, eclipse, manifest, android-activity

I'm working on an Android app using Eclipse and just started noticing a weird glitch.

When I deploy the app to my phone for some reason multiple app icons appear in my "Apps" folder area. Each icon brings me to a different class page within my app when tapped. Has anyone else experienced this as well?

Here's a screenshot of the issue when running the app from the emulator on my laptop.

[image: Weird bug]

Since the issue is appearing in the emulator I know that it isn't my phone that's causing the error.

Each of the icons you see in that screenshot represents a different activity in my manifest file.

Here's how the activity is set up in my manifest.

```
    <activity android:name=".MainJava">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".AppClass">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Would you say that this error being caused because of the way that I am setting up the activities? If so, how would you suggest that I edit the activities to fix this problem?

I've never seen this in any of the apps I've built before this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only `MainActivity(Launcher Activity) have intent filter with action as Main and category as Launcher`,

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

**And Remove this Two line For other Activity.**

Comment: Thanks. That's what I figured the problem was but I must have been too tired when I was trying to fix it the first time around.

Answer (score 2):

Change from:

```
<activity android:name=".MainJava">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".AppClass">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

To:

```
<activity android:name=".MainJava">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".AppClass">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

There should be only one `MAIN` and one `LAUNCHER`

Comment: can't we give everything in one <intent-filter> tag/

Comment: For the app that I'm building I need to have a navigation system and I don't believe if we put everything in one <intent-filter> tag I could do that. I may be wrong though.

Comment: You can use different intent filters, you just have have 2 mains/launchers